# Find directory and delete it's content but not itself

Tags: 12.04, files, directory, find

How do I find a directory and delete all it's content but not the directory itself?

```
find -type -d -name 'Tmp' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But this also deletes 'Tmp' directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
find . -type d -name 'Tmp' -exec sh -c 'rm -r "$0"/*' {} \;
```

Personally I would prefer to do this with bash, though:

```
shopt -s globstar
rm -r ./**/Tmp/*
```

With this, you can also easily ensure you're deleting hidden dotfiles, too:

```
shopt -s globstar dotglob
rm -r ./**/Tmp/*
```

Comment: I am not experienced with bash at all. What does shopt and globstar reference to?

Comment: `shopt` is the command to set options within bash -- `shopt -s globstar` sets (turns on) the globstar option. When this is set, `**` acts as a recursive glob -- so `**/*.foo` would search for every `*.foo` in the current directory *and* within all subdirectories. `dotglob` is another shell option, which makes globs match files beginning with a dot (which are hidden by default). I normally leave `shopt -s globstar extglob` in my `~/.bashrc` (extglob being another useful shell option).